# What's the reason that I hear the L's snap or something?

Tags: pronunciation

. . . look . . . looked . . .  [[audio source]](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/136)

The first L sound is plainly pronounced by BBC presenter. Yet the second one is from an Irish professor, and it seems to a bit vibrate by his tongue’s tightly wiggly snap or something else. What’s the reason I hear like that; what I said before is the real reason?

Comment: I'm no linguist, but I think it's just that part of the Irish accent is that the speaker *habitually* holds his tongue further back in his mouth when enunciating the L, and uses the very *tip* of his tongue. So when he releases it from the roof of his mouth to form the sound, there's more chance of you hearing a "click", even though he's making no explicit attempt to create that aspect of the sound in the first place.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Thank you I can imagine how he made the sound.

Comment: Well, like I say, I'm no linguist. Plus, of course, I wouldn't have even *heard* the effect if your question hadn't told me to listen closely. And even then, I barely know whether I'm actually hearing it, or just imagining what I think you hear. It's like if all *your* posts here always displayed the letter **g** with the bottom curl being "open", but all *mine* show the other kind of **g** with a "fully closed" oval. Which I would never normally notice, even though actually for me it's ***true right now!**

Comment: ...actually, it stopped being true when I clicked "Add Comment". Turns out the ELU font changes between "edit" and "display" mode for comments, and they use different "hooks" under the **g**. If tchrist ever stops by, I'm sure he could make a displayed comment use the other g, but I can't! :(

Comment: @Fumble: Don't need tchrist (well, not for this, anyway): `here's the other g`.

Comment: @Martha: Dang! I can "edit" questions and answers to see how such things are done - but I can't do that with comments, obviously! How do you *do* that?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: that's just code formatting, i.e. backticks.